# Colors not respected for Apex chart when using candlesticks

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, candlestick-chart

I have react web application using apex charts to show candlesticks along with additional moving average lines. Everything works fine except the line colors. I am passing array of colors to the chart options like following:

```
const options = {
    colors: ['#03A9F4', '#03A9F4', ...],
}
```

I know i am doing this right because when i switch to not using candlesticks the colors are respected.

I am rendering chart as follows:

```
<ReactApexChart
    series={series}
    options={options}
    type="candlestick"
    height={550}
/>
```

I was able to update the candlestick colors using plotoptions but the lines are all just rendered as black.

Not sure if this is even possible but it should be. Basically makes chart unreadable and if this is not possible will have to find a different technology.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/candlestick), try setting the colors in: options > plotOptions > candlestick, like this:

```
const options = {
    plotOptions: {
        candlestick: {
            colors: {
                upward: '#00B746',
                downward: '#EF403C'
            },
            wick: {
                useFillColor: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```